# Modify the text value of child node in xml file and save it (using python)

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

My xml file is :

```
<annotation>
    <folder>cancer</folder>
    <filename>cancer1.jpg</filename>
    <path>/Volumes/Windows/tongue-img/cancer/cancer1.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>3088</width>
        <height>2056</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>cancer</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1090</xmin>
            <ymin>869</ymin>
            <xmax>1807</xmax>
            <ymax>1379</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

I want to change the text value of child node of  1090
to the value by performing some arithmetic operations on it like subtract 10 from it.
The operation is performed and value is changed but its not saved to xml file i.e xml file is not updated it remains same.
Python code is :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('/Users/sripdeep/Desktop/Tongue_Cancer/leuko32.xml')  
root = tree.getroot()
X=10
print (root[6][4][0].text)
v1=root[6][4][0].text
v1 = int(v1) - X
print('New:')
print (v1)

print (root[6][4][1].text)
print (root[6][4][2].text)
print (root[6][4][3].text)

tree.write(open('C1.xml'))
```

The file C1.xml is not updated.

The output is (when the values are printed while running python):

```
Old text value:
1090
New text value:
1080
869
1807
1379
```

But the value remains 1090 in the modified xml file

Comment: Can you confirm that the tree has changed?

Comment: No it not changed the original files remains the same

Comment: I am referring to `tree`. Can you confirm that the object in python has changed.

Comment: the local variable values are changed but in the tree it does not, the value of v1 is changed in the python not in the tree

Comment: Try my answer. I'm not 100% sure, but I think it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is to modify the text. You have gotten the value, but not changed it in the underlying tree. To change to, you would just use the `=` operator.

```py
root[6][4][0].text = v1
```

Your final code would look like this:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('/Users/sripdeep/Desktop/Tongue_Cancer/leuko32.xml')  
root = tree.getroot()
X=10
print (root[6][4][0].text)
v1=root[6][4][0].text
v1 = int(v1) - X
print('New:')
print (v1)

root[6][4][0].text = str(v1)

print (root[6][4][1].text)
print (root[6][4][2].text)
print (root[6][4][3].text)

tree.write(open('C1.xml', 'w'))
```

Comment: It gives the below error:                                                                                        
cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).__name__)

TypeError: cannot serialize 1080 (type int)

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('./sample.xml')  
root = tree.getroot()
X=10
print (root[6][4][0].text)
v1=root[6][4][0].text
v1 = int(v1) - X
print('New:')
print (v1)

root[6][4][0].text = str(v1)
print (root[6][4][1].text)
print (root[6][4][2].text)
print (root[6][4][3].text)

tree.write('C1.xml')
```