# Editing xml child node text by finding child nodes based on name

Tags: python, xml, nodes, lxml

I would like to alter the text of a child node for an xml file parsed using python. I know the name of the childnodes but I can't seem to find the right sytax to point to the childnode, or the fact that the childnode name has a colon in it is throwing things off (I can't tell which).

For editing a childnode's text where you know the text that needs replacing already, I see that you can do this using:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("myxmlfile.xml")

for node in tree.xpath("//*[.='old text that I want to replace']"):
        node.text = "new name to insert"
```

However, I would like to do this the other way around: identify the node by a specified name, and then edit the inner text.

Additionally..

I can see from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086634/modify-the-text-value-of-child-node-in-xml-file-and-save-it-using-python) that you can directly point to the childnode and edit it through indexing. But I am wondering if there's a way to do this like the example mentioned above in case there are multiple entries using the same child node names throughout the xml file (lazy but efficient).

---

An example xml snippet:

```
<ns1:Block xmlns:ns1="http://www.somewebsite.com" id="Block-2"> 
  <ns1:Name>---INSERT NAME---</ns1:Name>  
  <ns1:BlockCode>TBD</ns1:BlockCode>  
  <ns1:BlockGroup>  
    <ns1:Priority>1</ns1:Priority>  
    <ns1:Ranking>High</ns1:Ranking>
  </ns1:BlockGroup>
</ns1:Block>
```

---

For the above snippet of the xml I'm trying to alter, I've been able to find the child element values by using e.g.:

```
ns = {'ns1': 'http://www.somewebsite.com'}

for group in tree.findall('ns1:BlockGroup', ns):
    priority = group.find('ns1:Priority', ns)
    print(priority.text)

>>>Out: 1
```

But in attempting to set the value to something else I'm getting a TypeError:

```
for group in tree.findall('ns1:BlockGroup', ns):
    priority = group.find('ns1:Priority', ns)
    priority = 2

Out:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-aae075596b63> in <module>
      3 for group in tree.findall('ns1:BlockGroup', ns):
      4     priority = group.find('ns1:Priority', ns)
----> 5     priority.text = 2
      6 

src/lxml/etree.pyx in lxml.etree._Element.text.__set__()

src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi in lxml.etree._setNodeText()

src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi in lxml.etree._createTextNode()

src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi in lxml.etree._utf8()

TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'int'
```

Any helpful links or advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The part before the colon is a namespace. Read about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces

Comment: Thanks @MichaelButscher that's super useful! I'm able to query the text for the example child in this post which is "Priority" using: 

 ``` for group in tree.findall('{http://www.somewebsite.com}BlockGroup'): priority = group.find('{http://www.somewebsite.com}Priority') ```

But that's just reading, do you perhaps know how to go from that to actually changing the priority.text to something else? I tried but it becomes an int versus byte error

Comment: Show the code and the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question (not as comment).

Comment: If you're just changing the value, try changing `priority = 2` to `priority.text = "2"`. (The value must be quoted.)

Comment: A little late to reply to this, but that worked! Thank you @DanielHaley !!